# ValidationRule vs Behavior in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, behavior, validationrule

Say I am trying to implement a piece of functionality in which a text box only allows integers to be inputted in by the user. I can implement this two ways, using a ValidationRule that checks whatever the user inputs and binding it to the text property through the XAML or I can create a new behavior and attach it to the control (not through binding).

Examples of the XAML on both:

Behavior:
`<TextBox behaviors:DigitsOnlyBehavior.IsDigitOnly="True"/>`

ValidationRule which binds to the Window's Text property

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding RelativeSource = "{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <utils:RestrictInputTypeValidator Restriction="IntegersOnly" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these approaches? When should I use them? Or is it a matter of preference?

Comment: Why don't you go with [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

With Behaviors I like and expect a "positive" scenario/workflow without errors. The focus is no errors. The user gets pretty quickly that when they type an '`a`' in the TextBox with Numeric behavior that it doesn't take it, that it's a numeric textbox, and this is how it works.

With Validation, the focus seems to be more on the error. I can have a Numeric TextBox, but I also don't take numbers beyond 100, if you type '`101`', I let you know that this is not acceptable. The focus here is to guide user into what is unacceptable by throwing a validation error.

Behavior Advantages:

- Prevention (you don't let the user shoot themselves in the foot) by entering bad data.
- Model stays clean. TextBox's Binding doesn't even hit the setter, as the behavior prevents it, hence, no XAML triggered back with PropertChanges, or ValidationErrors, etc.

Behavior Disadvantage:

-could be confusing , so if you put the logic not to accept '101', there is no default way to guide the user.

Comment: I am not really sure about both behavior advantage listed. As far as I know, using validation rule you can also prevent entering bad  data AND keep model clean by "not hitting the setter". I have used validation rule several times and it has all the features I need.

Comment: The only drawback I see using validation rule is:  How do you know in ViewModel if all fields are valid?  You can solve it by using Validation.Error="OnFieldValidationError" (but it is a custom solution)

Comment: If the validation fails, the property is not updated. So even with ValidationRules, the model remain clean.

Comment: well, except for the Validation Error that will be populated, and if you query/trigger on it, then the model isn't clean...